# Remove clouds in Sentinel 2A with R?

Tags: r, sentinel-2, cloud-cover

I would like to know how to remove clouds (create a cloud mask and its shadows) for Sentinel 2A data, using R (Windows). 
I have seen Information about this on Python or Matlab, but I work so far only in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentinel-2 level 1C come with cloud masks. You could open the product in SNAP, export the mask as GeoTiff and import it in R with `raster`. If you work with Sentinel-2 level 2A, (processed with sen2cor), you should also have some cloud layers

Then, to mask out the clouds, you can use `mask`. If you want to mask out all the bands of a Sentinel-2 image, stack them together (check `?stack` or `?brick` - for that you first need to have the same resolution - check `?aggregate` and `?disaggregate`

`test<-mask(S2_image_stack, cloud_mask)`

Comment: Where are the cloud masking files located within the `SAFE` level 2A folder? I'm only seeing a bunch of `gml` files...